# Main file and menu

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu, navigation-drawer

Not to repeat the code several times by extending the activities from a basic root file (BaseActivity). I have two menus for activities: one main and one drawer menu. Is it possible to write the java code on a single page so as not to have to repeat it every time?

```
public class MyListSiteActivity extends BaseActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  {

    // other code


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_list_site);


    // Drawer menu
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dlMenu);
    toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvMenu);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    // other code

    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    //primary menu
    if (id == R.id.login) {
        Intent intentLogin = new Intent(this, Login.class);
        this.startActivity(intentLogin);
        return true;
    } else  if (id == R.id.setting){
        return true;
    }


    // drawer menu
    if (toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    // drawer menu
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.insertSite:
            Intent intentSiteActivity = new Intent(this, InsertSiteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentSiteActivity);
            return true;
        case R.id.myListSite:
            Intent intentMyListSite = new Intent(this, MyListSiteActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentMyListSite);
            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    }

}
```

BaseActivity:

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle;

    // other code


    // other code

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);

    // other code




    }


}
```

When I try to put the menu code on the file on BaseActivity, it always marks me error.

Comment: Use Fragments instead of setting drawer in every activity.

Comment: Is it not possible to do this without using fragments?

Comment: It is possible but I will never recommend this.